# How do I dynamically load dll outside project?

Tags: c#, dll

How can I dynamically load a DLL?

*Please **don't** suggest:*

1. Don't suggest GAC, because the DLL is already made and can't be changed or updated.
2. Don't suggest hintpath, `Assembly.LoadFrom(...)` since this functionality works at debugging not outside the project.

If I copy that DLL/exe onto a test machine outside the project then it shows an error: could not load .dll.

I also asked a question [at the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/99691cc4-27df-48e7-b4aa-377f74109425?prof=required).

Could anyone help me?

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: What do you mean by "since this functionality works at debugging"? `Assembly.LoadFrom` seems to fit your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile) works just fine for this.

If you are getting [`BadImageFormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx), check whether the assembly you are trying to load is compiled for the same platform target (x86 or x64) as the assembly doing the loading.

**Update based on comments**

Sounds like you are trying to load a .NET 2.0 assembly into a .NET 4.0 application, and you have already put the following in your application configuration file:

```
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />    
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

In that case, check to make sure your configuration file is getting deployed on your target machine alongside your executable. For example, if your application is called `MyProgram.exe`, your configuration file should be called `MyProgram.exe.config` - *and it needs to be copied to the same folder as the executable on your target machine to have any effect* - the framework will load this file when it starts up, if it exists.

Comment: No, It not gives BadImageFormatException. Now I am getting new error mixed mode assembly is built against 'V2.... I already used in app.config file below code.But still gives error.It has same condition ie, works in debug but not outside the project.  Could u help me?                                                                                                                         <configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: Suggest editing your original question, including *full* details of the error message you are getting. However, I've updated my answer. Good luck...

Comment: I got solution, just need to copy xml file along with dll generated in bin folder.xml file contains app.config file data.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try using assembly.loadfile function instead of loadfrom. It will work outside the project also. 2) If u got assembly mixed mode error then, just need to copy xml file along with dll generated in bin folder.xml file contains app.config file data. Code in app.config file is...

also check link... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/99691cc4-27df-48e7-b4aa-377f74109425